# Simplify $R:=0^*+0^*1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm trying to simplify the following REGEX:

$$R:=0^*+0^*1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

$R$ is the result of transforming a GNFA that recognizes $L:= \{w \in \{0,1\}^* | \left(\forall \ i \in \left[1,|w|-2\right]\cap \mathbb{N}\right)\ w_iw_{i+1}w_{i+2} \neq 101\}$

I already know that there exists $R':=0^*\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$ such that $L(R)=L(R')=L$

Any hints?

Comment: Your $R'$ looks fairly simple already. Are you trying to get it even simpler? Or, in other words, what is your criterion for being simple _enough_? Would $(\varepsilon+000^*)1$ count as simpler than $(1+000^*1)$, for example?

Comment: I think you're not going to get simpler than $0^*(1 + 000^*)0^*$.

Comment: @Troposphere As you can see $R$ and $R'$ have a common part $E=\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$. $R'$ extends $E$ from the left just by $0^*$. That is $R'=\color{green}{0^*}E$ where $R=\color{red}{0^*+0^*1}E$

Comment: @TheoBendit: Perhaps $0?(1+000?)^*0?$, if we consider a Kleene star as inherently more complex than alternation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$R:=0^*+0^*1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$
$$R=0^*+\left(\epsilon + 00^*\right)1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$
$$R=0^*+\left(\epsilon + 0\left(\epsilon + 00^*\right)\right)1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$
$$R=0^*+\left(\epsilon + 0+ 000^*\right)1\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$
$$R=0^*+\left(1 + 01 + 000^*1\right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

By the commutativity of $+$ in $\{0,1\}^*$ $$R=0^*+\left(1 + 000^*1 + 01\right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

By the associativity of $+$ in $\{0,1\}^*$ $$R=0^*+\left(\left(1 + 000^*1\right) + 01\right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

Since the concatenation is distributive over the union, then

$$R=0^*+\left(1 + 000^*1\right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^* + 01\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

$$R=\left( \epsilon +\left(1 + 000^*1\right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*\right)0^* + 01\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

$$R=\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^* + 01\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

$$R=\left(\epsilon + 01 \right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^*0^*$$

Comment: How do your final answer gets the word "00000001" that should be in the language?

Comment: $ \left(\epsilon \right)\left(1+000^*1\right)^10^0 \rightarrow \left(1+000^*1\right) \rightarrow 000^*1$. Did you get it?

Comment: Yup right, sorry :)